# Autosizing iOS using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, multiscreen

Is the feature of autosizing using storyboard disappeared in Xcode 6.3? And how can I develop for multiscreen (iPhone/iPad)?

I am sorry for my poor question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better solution is AutoLayout.Just,google AutoLayout in iOS.Beside,you can use autoresizing in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the file inspector (the window is on the right) and make sure "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" are checked.